Is there a way to keep sequences when exporting my Zebra print file to a .prn?
I have a Zebra label designed in Zebra Designer 2 that has some text, text variables that are prompted from the user and a sequence counter number that prints numbers from 1 to chosen quantity on the labels.
When I print to file to generate a .prn file. I'm not sure how the variables and counter work? Are they included in the .prn file code? When I print to file it seems that the code generated is for a single label with no choice for variables.
I'm trying to integrate the printing to a html file but I need the variable prompts to still work

The number generators and variables work only inside of the Zebra Designer software. Once the label is exported/printed to a text file for further processing outside the Designer these things don't exist anymore!
For this you have to write your own software parsing/processing the text file (ZPL Code) and filling out your text with number sequences etc.

Thanks for the info. I was afraid of that. Are there any examples of how this can be achieved with a couple of variables and a counter number? The labels only need to have two words (input by the operator) and a counter that prints the numbers 1- x where x is the number of labels required

I don't know any examples for this. It's basically a text search and replace regarding the label itself.

@MattLaming Please mark my answer as accepted, if it was ok for you
